# How to resend url from one web server to another thru php

Tags: php, nginx, curl

I need to resend url from one web server to another thru php.
I got web app on 192.168.5.10, and i want send specific REST url on 192.168.5.50. For example:
GET http://192.168.5.10/?page=mypage - will be processed by 192.168.5.10 server
GET http://192.168.5.10/getsomedata/ - will be processed by 192.168.5.50 server
With $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"] i parse url`s and if url === "getsomedata" i              use cURL and send request GET http://192.168.5.50/getsomedata/ and i get a response. But if i echo this response like this:

```
        header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
        http_response_code(200);
        echo ($response);
```

I still receive 404 error with full data from http://192.168.5.10/getsomedata/ server.
How can i fix it without re-configuring nginx server?
Thanks.

Comment: You are very unclear and need to show your code and not the response... what happens when /getsomedata/ is in the url how did you setup the link and where is the code?

Comment: From client i send request on http://192.168.5.10/getsomedata/ . At server i parse url and resend request to http://192.168.5.50/getsomedata/ using cURL, i receive response - and for now everything is ok. Now i must this response send as a response for http://192.168.5.10/getsomedata/ request - i do it by echo $response with code from the post, client get response with all data i need, but with 404 status - i want to know why?